# Proximal operators on Balls (Projection)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, projective-geometry, proximal-operators

I was following [Gabriel Peyre - Dictionary Learning for Denoising](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/gpeyre/numerical-tours/blob/master/matlab/sparsity_5_dictionary_learning_denoising.ipynb) tutorial, In section 21 it is given Proximal operator over a ball $B_\epsilon$ of radius $\epsilon$ as
$$\text{Proj}_{B_\epsilon(y)}(u) = y + (u-y) \max({1 , \frac{\epsilon}{||{u-y}||} })$$

I would like to know the proof of the above statement. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to solve $\min \{ f(x) | x \in C \}$,
where $f(x) = {1\over 2} \|u-x\|^2$ and $C = \bar{B}(y, \epsilon)$. Since $C$ is compact, we know there is a solution $\hat{x}$. Since the Euclidean norm is strictly convex, we see that the solution is unique.

Since $f$ and $C$ are convex, we have that $\hat{x}$ solves the problem **iff** $D f(\hat{x}) (x-\hat{x}) \ge 0$ for all $x \in C$.

In this particular problem, this says that $\hat{x}$ solves the problem **iff** $\langle \hat{x}-u, x-\hat{x} \rangle \ge 0$ for all $x$ such that $\|x-y\| \le \epsilon$.

If $\|u-y\| \le \epsilon$, we have
$\langle 0, x-\hat{x} \rangle = 0$ for all $x$, so we see that $\hat{x}=u$ is the solution.

If $\|u-y\| > \epsilon$, let $\hat{x} = {\epsilon \over \|u-y\|} (u-y)+y$, then
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle \hat{x}-u, x-\hat{x} \rangle &=& (1-{\epsilon \over \|u-y\|}) \langle y-u, x-\hat{x} \rangle \\
&=& (1-{\epsilon \over \|u-y\|}) \langle y-u, x-y+ {\epsilon \over \|u-y\|} (y-u)\rangle \\
&=& (1-{\epsilon \over \|u-y\|}) \left( \langle y-u, x-y \rangle + \langle y-u, {\epsilon \over \|u-y\|} (y-u)\rangle \right) \\
&=& (1-{\epsilon \over \|u-y\|}) \left( \langle y-u, x-y \rangle + \epsilon \|u-y\| \right) \\
&\ge& 0
\end{eqnarray}
Where the inequality follows from Cauchy-Schwarz and $\|x-y\| \le \epsilon$.

Combining the two results gives the desired answer.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, How did you derive $\hat{x} = {\epsilon \over \|u-y\|} (u-y)+y$ for $\|u-y\| > \epsilon$

Comment: Draw a picture of a ball around $y$ with some $u$ outside. Then $\hat{x}$ must lie on this line on the boundary of the ball.

Comment: Yeah i got the intuition, actually i was wondering about the theory for any distance function other than euclidean norm?

Comment: There may not be a unique minimizer for norms such as $l_1, l_\infty$?

Comment: What about bregman divergences they are convex and have a unique minimizer? How should i go about finding an analytical form for such a distance? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what a Bregman  divergence is.

Comment: How to derive $\hat{x} = {\epsilon \over \|u-y\|} (u-y)+y$ analytically? I am able to get it intuitively by considering a circle but how to arrive at such a form? (Bregman divergences are also distance functions with special properties )

Comment: If you use Lagrange multipliers to solve $\min \{ {1 \over 2} \|u-x\|^2 | \|x-y\|^2 = \epsilon^2 \}$ you will get the desired form.

Comment: oops thats makes sense thanks

Comment: @D.W.: Thanks for catching that.